# Avoid Access Denied when writing to file

Tags: c#, multithreading, file, logging, trace

I am logging to file with the following method

```
public static void LogDataContractToFile(string XMLStringToLog, string filePathAndName)
{
    FileInfo fileinfoMaster;
    FileInfo fileinfoLog;
    string fileName = string.Empty;
    int tmpInt = 0;
    filePathAndName = filePathAndName.ToLower();

    while (true)
    {
        lock (LogDataContractToFileLock)
        {
            if (!_workingWithFiles.Contains(filePathAndName))
            {
                _workingWithFiles.Add(filePathAndName);
                break;
            }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    try
    {
        #region Create XMLFile

        if ((tmpInt = filePathAndName.LastIndexOf('.')) > 0)
            fileName = filePathAndName.Remove(tmpInt, filePathAndName.Length - tmpInt);
        else
            fileName = filePathAndName;

        fileinfoMaster = new FileInfo(fileName + ".xml");
        fileinfoLog = new FileInfo(fileinfoMaster.DirectoryName + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileinfoMaster.Name) + ".log");

        if ((fileinfoMaster.Exists && !fileinfoLog.Exists) ||
            (!fileinfoMaster.Exists && fileinfoLog.Exists))
        {
            fileinfoMaster.Delete();
            fileinfoLog.Delete();
        }

        //Se så att filen är 50 MB eller mindre annars arkivera
        if (fileinfoMaster.Exists && fileinfoLog.Length > 52428800)
        {
            tmpInt = FileWriter.FileCount(fileinfoLog.DirectoryName, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileinfoMaster.Name) + "*.log");
            fileinfoLog.MoveTo(Path.Combine(fileinfoLog.DirectoryName, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileinfoLog.Name) + "_" + tmpInt.ToString() + ".log"));
            CreateLogDataMasterFile(Path.Combine(fileinfoMaster.DirectoryName, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileinfoMaster.Name) + "_" + tmpInt.ToString() + ".xml"), fileinfoLog.Name);
            fileinfoLog = new FileInfo(fileinfoMaster.DirectoryName + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileinfoMaster.Name) + ".log");
        }

        if (!fileinfoMaster.Exists)
        {
            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(fileinfoMaster.DirectoryName);
            if (info.Exists == false)
                info.Create();

            CreateLogDataMasterFile(fileinfoMaster.FullName, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileinfoMaster.Name) + ".log");
        }

        #endregion

        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(fileinfoMaster.DirectoryName + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileinfoMaster.Name) + ".log"))
        {
            sw.Write(XMLStringToLog);
            sw.Flush();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        lock (LogDataContractToFileLock)
        {
            _workingWithFiles.Remove(filePathAndName);
        }
    }

}

private static void CreateLogDataMasterFile(string filepathAndName, string dataFileName)
{
    XmlTextWriter xmlWriter;
    using (xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(filepathAndName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
        xmlWriter.WriteDocType("DataLog", null, null, "<!ENTITY data SYSTEM \"" + dataFileName + "\">");
        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("root");
        xmlWriter.WriteRaw("&data;");
        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
        xmlWriter.Flush();
    }
}
```

Several different threads might write to file at the same time and in some cases they will write to the same file. To avoid problems with `access denied, used by other process` I have implemented some logic as you can see.

The problem is that I am still getting `access denied, used by other process` from time to time.

I have looked at the build in tracers like the TextWriterTraceListener and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener(v=vs.110).aspx) I can see the following note :

> If an attempt is made to write to a file that is in use or
>   unavailable, the file name is automatically prefixed by a GUID.

So it looks like even Microsoft has problems with this? Is it a Windows problem? Is there any way to handle this becides generating a new file? Generating a new file will mess of the data flow in files a lot!

Comment: Another option (per @spender answer) is to block callers. I am unsure if you did it correctly, would expect a `lock` around write to file method.

Comment: Im blocking other callers to the same file with the first while and lock code. So if there is already a thread writing to the specific file no other will be able to until it is "checked in" again.

Comment: `lock` before and after writing will not ensure (from my point of view) what 2 or more threads will not be able to pass first lock and won't try concurrently write something into file. E.g. think about locking call to a whole `LogDataContractToFile` method. Lock has to be hold until operation is completed, you are either release it earlier or locking (second `lock`) when it's already too late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Don't write to a file from multiple threads. Create a single thread that is reponsible for file writes, and have it read what to write from a [ConcurrentQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Any thread that needs to write should just add data to the queue.

Comment: So I should create one thread (and only one) that writes to all files and then have a queue with objects(containing data and file metadata) for this one thread that all other threads places objects in?

Comment: "to write all files"... no not necessarily, but for a single thread to take all responsibility for writing data to a single file, such that it's not possible for two threads to simultaneously write to the same file.

Comment: Okay, so what you suggests is that I have a collection of objects that holds a thread and metadata about that file. When another thread arrives I take out this object, uses the thread in this object and writes to the specific file. The question is what will happen if 2 threads instructs this stored thread to write to a file at the same time? Will I have to handle some kind of synchronization?

Comment: That's why you have the queue. You don't instruct a write, you queue it. The writing thread dequeues write messages one at a time.